# Align in center Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I cant align the content generated by this code in center on my html page. CSS text-align:center didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8" src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=TzNNFcsZOvZ1jfLYlUKg1DXHmNfGLgB1&width=800&height=450" style="text-align: center"></script>
```

This is how the generated [code](http://ttime.me/imageprice.html) looks

Comment: what the hell you want to do my dear...:)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't centre a script. You might be talking about centring the content generated by the script but how would I know?

Comment: What you cant understand. When i put this code in html page, its stuck to the left of the page. I need to align it to the center...

Comment: Yes, okey, i would like to center the content generated by the script

Comment: 1) Right click the rendered element you want to align 2) pick a suitable selector 3) ? 4) add a style to align  it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can just add the following style

```
 ymaps{ margin:0 auto; }
```

In you stylesheet.

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/potur/1/edit?html,output)**

Comment: thank you for quite elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/f65qX/)

Wrap it in a `div` (with an ID of say "WrapperID")

Then add these rules:

```
#WrapperID {
    text-align:center;
}

#WrapperID > ymaps {
    display:inline-block!important;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why is this getting down-voted? This appears to make sense.

Comment: Doesn't work, tried it already

Comment: Why would you add another element for this while crossing your fingers and hoping the script places the shit right in there? @ArtyMcFly

Comment: @PeeHaa It is common for scripts to insert DOM elements right before or after the script tag, so it might make sense. It's a pretty good guess given the amount of info we've been given.

Comment: It's more common for elements inserted by scripts to at least have some identifier rendering the extra markup useless.